# Interface Builder cannot find .xib - Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I recently became interested in mobile app development and want to take my coding experience from elec. engring to the iphone. Im having trouble though. I am trying to compile my first app onto my phone (got it to run perfectly on the iOS simulator last night). However, upon compiling i get the following error:"Interface Builder XIB Compiler Error: Interface Builder could not open the document "xxx.xib" because it does not exist"

I've tried going into my target and setting Main Interface to xxx.xib and I still get the same error on both iPhone and iOS simulation. I've tried setting my interface to Xcode 4.6 and messing with the builds and views, still have the same issue. I built it from scratch - same issue.

All help appreciated. I know the default is building with story board, but I am following a book I am happy with and I want to go through it with the .xib because thats what the book uses. Thanks -

Answer (score 2):

Select your project (blue icon) in the project navigator then choose:

Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Make sure your xib file is on the list. You can add it by clicking the plus (+) icon on the lower left.

**UPDATE**:

Consider opening a new project as a sanity check. Change the background color and verify that it runs in the simulator. If it does then this will point to a project settings issue rather than an installation problem.

You may also want to look at the following [walkthrough](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html) by Apple. Hopefully following the steps will help illustrate anything you might be missing.

Apple also has a latest [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343) that I recommend you walkthrough. After completing please let me know if you are continuing to have this problem. The number of potential problems is greater than simply walking through the 15 min tutorial.

Comment: my xib file is added. i am having the exact same problem when adding a .storyboard file too. this is driving me insane

Comment: i can follow the walkthrough up to the point where i add a storyboard (or xib).. as soon as i add one the complier fails to find the file every single time.

Comment: *works to change colors and such, its a settings error for sure but i cannot find what the issue is

Comment: as a side note, if i create a brand new single view application and try to build it, the same error is encountered